# Create variables in data frame with for loop

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, transform

I have a main data frame (`mydata`) and two secondary ones (`df1`, `df2`) such as follows:

```
x <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
y <- c(5, 4, 3, 2, 1)
mydata <- data.frame(x)
df1 <- data.frame(y)
df2 <- data.frame(y)
df2$y <- y+1 #This way, the columns in the df have the same name but different values.
```

I want to create new columns in `mydata` based on a formula with the variables in `df1` and `df2` like this:

```
mydata$new1 <- mydata$x*df1$y
mydata$new2 <- mydata$x*df2$y
```

Is there a way I can do this with a for loop? This is what I had in mind:

```
for (i in 2) {
  mydata$paste0("new", i) <- mydata$x*dfpaste0(i)$y
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something along the lines of:

```
for (i in 1:2) {

  mydata[[as.symbol(paste0('new', i))]] <- mydata$x*get(paste0("df", i))$y

}
```

Answer (score 0):

We could also use `mget` to get all the object values in a `list`  and multiply with the concerned `vector`

```
mydata[paste0("new", 1:2)] <- mydata$x * data.frame(mget(paste0("df", 1:2)))
```